# Is this due to https encoding?

Tags: go, https

I am new to developing https websites and am seeing the following problem.  I am asking the website to simply return the product of the shell command "pwd"

In Go, the relevant lines are as follows:

```
            import (
               "os/exec"
            )

            out, err := exec.Command("pwd").Output()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(out)
```

the response appears to be encoded.

```
            [47 109 110 116 47 100 47 98 105 110 47 100 101 118 101 108 111 112 109 101 110 116 47 119 119 119 10]
```

Question: How can I retrieve the actual value?

Comment: The output is a byte array. Print it using `fmt.Println(string(out))`

Comment: @Burak Serdar, Thank you!!  How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: That is the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with https encoding. `Command` returns a `[]byte`, which you then proceed to print.

If you want the string representation of the output, you'd have to convert it:

```golang
fmt.Println(string(out))
```